# how can I put parameters in ElasticSearch curl post

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

The following is my linux shell code for insert one record to ElasticSearch:

```
username="Tom"
curl -XPOST 'http://192.168.0.1:9200/userdb/info/1' -d '{"user":$username}'
```

But it didn't work, it treated $username is a string not a variable. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose `$username` in double quotes since it's a string. That will work.

```
username="Tom"
curl -XPOST 'http://192.168.0.1:9200/userdb/info/1' -d "{\"user\":\"$username\"}"
                                                       ^           ^         ^  ^
                                                       |           |         |  |
                                                     here         here  and  here
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when I search it ,the result is :"_source":{"user":"$username"}, it didn't treat $username as a variable.

Comment: Strange, it works perfectly for me when in try in my shell. What kind of shell do you have?

Comment: I'm using #!/bin/bash

Comment: Oh you need double quotes all the way, otherwise the variable doesn't get expanded. See my answer and try again.

Comment: thank you so much, it works now. You are Linux and ES master :-)